# Autocount project won't build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an autocount project that should deploy in autocount 1.8 but when I try to build it I get the following errors:

- The type or namespace name 'LicenseStatusArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  in plugininit.cs
- The type or namespace name 'AccountantColumnChangedEventArgs' does not exist in the namespace 'BCE.AutoCount.Option' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    in options.cs
- The type name 'FormShownEventArgs' does not exist in the type 'BCE.AutoCount.MainEntry.FormMain' in option.cs and mainformscript.cs

Is this because of a licensing issue? I apologize if this isn't the right place to put this kind of question.

Comment: What does "autocount" refer to?

Comment: Autocount Accounting 1.8 again I apologize if this isn't right place for this question

Comment: If you open the references node in the solution explorer, does it show a reference to that assembly that should have the BCE namespace? if it does, it shouldn't show a warning sign. see the image in: https://wiki.autocountsoft.com/wiki/Exercise_1:_Build_My_First_Plug-In

Comment: Yes it shows the BCE namespace references